# Find Min Or Max in custom aggregate function postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, plpgsql

I'm new to Postgresql (I'm programming in PL/pgSQL, there's no much difference with sql).
I wrote my custome aggregate function, which has to find the min value, or max in an array of numeric. 
**This is the function aggregate code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION searchMaxValue (numeric[]) RETURNS numeric AS $$
DECLARE 
i numeric;
maxVal numeric;
BEGIN
maxVal = $1[1];
IF ARRAY_LENGHT($1,1) > 0 THEN --Checking whether the array is empty or  not
   <<confrontoMassimo>>
   FOREACH i IN ARRAY $1 LOOP --Looping through the entire array, passed as parameter
       IF maxVal <= $1[i] THEN
           maxVal := $1[i];
       END IF;
   END LOOP confrontoMassimo;
   ELSE
   RAISE NOTICE 'Invalid parameter % passed to the aggregate function',$1;
   --Raising exception if the parameter passed as argument points to null.
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot find Max value. Parameter % is null', $1
   USING HINT = 'You cannot pass a null array! Check the passed parameter';

END IF;
RETURN maxVal;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

 CREATE AGGREGATE searchMaxValueArray (numeric)
(
sfunc = array_append,
stype = numeric[],
finalfunc = searchMaxValue,
initCond = '{}'
);
```

The problem is, that it doesn't work as expected. What is the problem?

Comment: *" it doesn't work as expected."*  is not a great problem description. Whether it throws any error? Does it give different results than expected? If so, show some example of what's expected and what you got from the function, etc.

Comment: `ARRAY_LENGHT` should be `ARRAY_LENGTH`. Is it just a typo or your issue is related to that ?

Comment: Can't you just use `unnest` along with `MAX/MIN` to accomplish this? i.e.: `select MAX(id) FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AS t(id);`

Comment: "I'm new to Postgres" and "I wrote my custom aggregate function" are just not two things one sees together very much.  Writing a custom aggregation function is one of the more complicated things to do in any database.

Comment: You should perform the calculation of the maximum in `sfunc` rather than in `finalfunc`, the array could become too large to handle. I see no fundamental problem with your function, please describe the malfunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, there's a small typo in your function; `ARRAY_LENGHT` should be `ARRAY_LENGTH`.

Aside from that, the only issue I can see is here:

```
FOREACH i IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
    IF maxVal <= $1[i] THEN
        ...
```

In a [`FOREACH` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY), the target variable `i` isn't the array index, it's the array element itself. In other words, the loop should be:

```
FOREACH i IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
    IF maxVal <= i THEN
        maxVal := i;
    END IF;
END LOOP
```

With those changes, it seems to work as expected: https://rextester.com/FTWB14034

Comment: Though as @Laurenz mentioned above, this is a _very_ inefficient way of approaching it. Not only are you potentially building huge arrays, you're copying the whole array every time you append a new value. But I suppose if you wanted something efficient, you'd just call `MAX()` ;)

Comment: That's what i was looking for. I thought that it worked like Java. Thanks, I fixed the issue as you suggested, and it's ok!